# How to use enterprise library for logging and exception handling purpose?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, logging, .net-4.0, enterprise-library-5

I have my project design as below:

1. MVC 4 (presentation)(using ninject as DI)
2. WCF Service (BAL)
3. DAL library - (Core ADO.NET)
4. Common library (contain DTO and utility)

Now, I want to add - Exception management and Logging mechanism.

Can any one suggest how i could use enterprise library withing this ?

Additionally, it would be also find if any one can suggest validation mechanism to manage through enterprise library - client side and server side.

Enterprise library 5 - .NET framework 4.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Sounds you like are looking for a logging solution like log4net or NLog? They are two of the most popular .NET logging frameworks. For exceptions you can also look at using ELMAH.

There are also commercial products that you can get to provide much more advanced functionality around exceptions and logs. Those products typically allow you to configure log4net or NLog to forward the data to them. Commercial products can aggregate all your logs together and give you alerts, dashboards, etc. [Stackify](http://www.stackify.com) is one product that can do both exceptions and logs together. There are also products that only do exceptions or logs like [Airbrake](https://airbrake.io/) or [Papertrail](https://papertrailapp.com/).

Comment: Have you used stackify for yourself ?